# How to delete cookies for a library mechanicalsoup

Tags: python, python-2.7

How to delete cookies for a library mechanicalsoup ?

```
import mechanicalsoup as ms
Browser = ms.StatefulBrowser()
```

Comment: It should be ```Browser.session.cookies.clear()```

Comment: how delete history !!